# problems completing and then analyzing a hierarchical (2x2 repeated measures) multiple imputation with pan in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, missing-data

Primary issue:  after running multiple imputation with pan and then analysis via lmer/glmer, I am getting intercepts with absurd values for the df (e.g., 55125928384804199838284828486266882208420242662020648820286.000

I have data from a 2x2 repeated measures design with 3 DVs, 1 DV is similar to a measure of reaction time (RT, continuous) and the other two are count data (e.g., number of errors)) collected from field research with a special population.  there is some missing data so I need to run a multiple imputation (MI) procedure on before I conduct my final analyses.

to prepare, I've been working with an older (complete) dataset from a 2x2 repeated measures design with RT as a DV.  I deleted abut 11% of the data and then attempted to use PAN for the MI procedure ( this process, overall seems to be quite successful).  My code is as follows:

```
old_missing <- read_csv("olddatap2.csv", 
                    col_types = cols(
                      condition = col_factor(levels = c("Abrupt", "Gradual")), 
                      location = col_factor(levels = c("Repeated","nRepeated")), 
                      rt = col_number(), 
                      subject = col_factor(levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
                                                      "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
                                                      "21", "22", "23", "24", "25"))))

olm <- as.data.frame(old_missing)

### Setup the imputation model (designed to be equivalent to a 2x2 repeated measures ANOVA
fml <- rt ~ condition*location + (1|subject) + (1|condition:subject) + (1|location:subject)

### Run the imputation
imp <- panImpute(olm, formula=fml, n.burn=100, n.iter=50, m=11, seed = 1234)

### list of the imputed datasets
implist <- mitmlComplete(imp, print="all")

### fit null model
fit <- with(implist, lmer(rt ~ 1 + (1|subject)))

### final parameter estimates (Rubin's rules)
testEstimates(fit, var.comp=TRUE)

### fit model of interest 
fit2 <- with(implist, lmer(rt ~ condition*location + (1|subject) + (1|condition:subject) + (1|location:subject)))
testEstimates(fit2, var.comp=TRUE)
testModels(fit, fit2, method = "D1")
```

right now, the testModels() function is erroring out:

```
error in sapply(model, lme4::fixef)[dpar,]:
incorrect number of dimensions
```

not terribly concerned about this right now but it's something I'll need to deal with eventually

Importantly, the results from the model of interest (fit2) are a good representation of the actual (complete) data.

Now, when I try to replicate this process with my current data (I set it to run each DV separately) problems arise.  below is the code that I use for the newer data:

```
lfdata3 <- read_csv("lfdata3.csv", 
                col_types = cols(dv3 = col_number(), 
                                 cond = col_factor(levels = c("A", "B")), 
                                 dv2 = col_number(), 
                                 dv1 = col_number(), 
                                 pre = col_factor(levels = c("PL", "nPL")), 
                                 Subject = col_factor(levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))))
olm <- as.data.frame(lfdata3) ### make sure data is set to be a data.frame
### Setup the imputation model
fml_dv1 <- dv1 ~ cond*pre + (1|Subject) + (1|cond:Subject) + (1|pre:Subject)
fml_dv2 <- dv2 ~ cond*pre + (1|Subject) + (1|cond:Subject) + (1|pre:Subject)
fml_dv3 <- dv3 ~ cond*pre + (1|Subject) + (1|cond:Subject) + (1|pre:Subject)

### Run the imputation
imp_dv1<- panImpute(olm, formula=fml_dv1, n.burn=100, n.iter=50, m=7, seed = 1234)
imp_dv2<- panImpute(olm, formula=fml_dv2, n.burn=100, n.iter=50, m=7, seed = 1234)
imp_dv3<- panImpute(olm, formula=fml_dv3, n.burn=100, n.iter=50, m=7, seed = 1234)

### list of the imputed datasets
implist_dv1<- mitmlComplete(imp_dv1, print="all")
implist_dv2<- mitmlComplete(imp_dv2, print="all")
implist_dv3<- mitmlComplete(imp_dv3, print="all")

### fit null models
fit_dv1 <- with(implist_dv1, lmer(dv1 ~ 1 + (1|Subject)))
fit_dv2 <- with(implist_dv2, lmer(dv2 ~ 1 + (1|Subject)))
fit_dv3 <- with(implist_dv3, lmer(dv3 ~ 1 + (1|Subject)))

### final parameter estimates (Rubin's rules)
testEstimates(fit_dv1, var.comp=TRUE)
testEstimates(fit_dv2, var.comp=TRUE)
testEstimates(fit_dv3, var.comp=TRUE)

### fit model of interest 
fit2_dv1 <- with(implist_dv1, lmer(dv1~ cond*pre + (1|Subject) + (1|cond:Subject) + (1|pre:Subject)))
fit2_dv2 <- with(implist_dv2, glmer(dv2~ cond*pre+ (1|Subject) + (1|cond:Subject) + (1|pre:Subject), family = "poisson"))
fit2_dv3 <- with(implist_dv3, glmer(dv3 ~ cond*pre+ (1|Subject) + (1|cond:Subject) + (1|pre:Subject), family = "poisson"))
```

the two count data DVs error out here with the following output:

```
Error in eval(family$initialize, rho) :   negative values not allowed for the 'Poisson' family
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

They will complete without error if I run them with a lmer() command without the "poisson" classification.

I then continue with the following which produces an interesting error.

```
### final parameter estimates for the model of interest(Rubin's rules)
testEstimates(fit2_dv1, var.comp=TRUE)
testEstimates(fit2_dv2, var.comp=TRUE)
testEstimates(fit2_dv3, var.comp=TRUE)
```

The output shows intercepts with absurd values for the df (e.g., 55125928384804199838284828486266882208420242662020648820286.000

```
testModels(fit_dv1, fit2_dv1, method = "D1")
testModels(fit_dv2, fit2_dv2, method = "D1")
testModels(fit_dv3, fit2_dv3, method = "D1")
```

these still do not work:

```
Error in sapply(model, lme4::fixef)[dpar, ] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

Why am i getting  Xe*60 df for the intercept?  do I have some errors in my code that I am missing?